# Genexus GAM - cambiar schema por defecto

Tags: genexus

Tengo una aplicacion Genexus + Gam, pero en el hosting contratado solo admite el schema dbo.
Fui a las propiedades del datasource de GAM e indique el schema dbo.

[image: Data source Gam]
Hice rebuild all, en el web.config esta correctamente indicado el schema dbo para ambos datasource: Default y GAM, pero al ejecutar mi aplicación recibo este error, donde claramente todavia utiliza el schema gam

> Invalid object name 'gam.SysPar'.

Que sugieren revisar?

Comment: ¿Probaste una vez cambiada la propiedad volver a ejecutar desde el IDE: Tools > GAM > Create database tables e initialize metadata?